# Hadoop on a single node vagrant VM - Connection refused when starting start-all.sh

Tags: hadoop, vagrant

I have created a vagrant virtual machine and installed hadoop on that.
Only a single server cluster.
But when I try to start my hadoop on the machine it gives the following error:

mkdir: Call From master/127.0.1.1 to localhost:9000 failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused; For more details see:  http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/ConnectionRefused

And idea? The machine is named as master. The server is an Ubuntu.

Thanks!

Comment: Try deleting the line with `127.0.1.1` from `/etc/hosts` file.

Comment: Hi Rajesh, still the same issue, doesnt seem to help :( any other idea?

Answer (score 1):

This because hdfs nodes are not running go to,

```
cd HADOOP_HOME/sbin
./start-all.sh
```

Will start all processes.